# Hit ClassCastException

Tags: blackberry, popup, classcastexception

I am calling this class which is `PopupScreen`.

```java
public class Custom_LoadingScreen extends PopupScreen {
private VerticalFieldManager vfm;
private Util_AnimateGifField anmtFldCycle = null;
private GIFEncodedImage gifImgCycle;

public Custom_LoadingScreen() {
    super(new VerticalFieldManager());
    Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidTransparentBackground(
            Color.BLACK, 190);
    setBackground(bg);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(),
            Border.STYLE_TRANSPARENT));

    gifImgCycle = (GIFEncodedImage) GIFEncodedImage
            .getEncodedImageResource("LoadingSpinner.gif");
    anmtFldCycle = new Util_AnimateGifField(gifImgCycle,
            Field.FIELD_HCENTER);

    vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
        }
    };
    int padding = (Display.getHeight() - 16) / 2;
    if (padding > 0) {
        anmtFldCycle.setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    vfm.add(anmtFldCycle);
    add(vfm);
}

//public void Popupscreen() {
    //Main.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
//}

public boolean keyDown(int keycode, int status) {
    if (Keypad.key(keycode) == Keypad.KEY_ESCAPE) {
        Main.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.keyDown(keycode, status);
}
}
```

In a button, I pushed it before goes to next screen.

```java
financebtn = new Custom_ButtonField(finance, financeactive,
            financeactive) {
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Custom_LoadingScreen());
            Main.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                //  Main.getUiApplication().popScreen();
                    Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                            new Main_NewsDetail());
                }

            }, 1 * 1000, false);

            return true;
        }
    };
    add(financebtn);
```

The result give me `Uncaught:ClassCastException`. I can call another class which is similar to `custom_loadingscreen` also popupscreen. It work fine.

I also tried call this class in another button yet still same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at your `Custom_LoadingScreen` code, there's only one place where you are doing a cast:

```java
gifImgCycle = (GIFEncodedImage) GIFEncodedImage
        .getEncodedImageResource("LoadingSpinner.gif");
```

So, that's a good place to start looking.  If you Google for **"BlackBerry GIFEncodedImage ClassCastException"**, you'll find this thread:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/GIFEncodedImage-in-BlackBerry-OS7/td-p/1228959

The problem is that, for optimization, BlackBerry likes to convert images to the PNG format, which most smartphones work best with.  So, what's happening here is that your GIF image is actually being converted to a PNG image.  Therefore, when you call the `getEncodedImageResource()` method, the object you are getting back may actually be of type `PNGEncodedImage`, not `GIFEncodedImage`, and you get the exception.  Sneaky, huh?

You can solve it a few ways.

1. In the **Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml** file, you can uncheck the setting that specifies that images are converted to PNG (**Build** tab -> **Convert image files to png**)
2. You can trick the build system by renaming your GIF file to something like **LoadingSpinner.agif**.  The toolset doesn't recognize the .agif extension, and therefore won't try to convert it.  If you do this, of course, remember to change the filename in your Java code, too, when loading it.
3. You can change the code to use `PNGEncodedImage`, or test the object like this:

```java
EncodedImage img = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("LoadingSpinner.gif");
if (img instanceof GIFEncodedImage) {
   // cast to GIFEncodedImage
} else if (img instanceof PNGEncodedImage) {
   // cast to PNGEncodedImage
}
```

Number (1) will lose the non-PNG to PNG conversion optimization for all your non-PNG images, not just this one.

Number (2) does look a little ugly.  The benefit of doing this, though, is that you can disable this behaviour for just this one image.  If most of your images are not PNG images, it might be valuable to let BlackBerry optimize for you, for the other images.  But, maybe this one needs to be a GIF.  So, #2 lets you handle this one as a special case.

I'm just guessing that this image might be an **animated** GIF?  Is that right?  If so, you probably want to keep it as a GIF, so you won't want to do number (3), which lets it be converted to a PNG, and uses it as such.

Comment: Thanks again, i chose number 2 because 1 and 3 not suitable

Comment: @AlanLai.  You're welcome.  Just a note: you now have enough points to Upvote answers (with the arrow buttons next to each answer), in addition to Accepting answers.  Ideally, you would do that, too.  In fact, if one of your questions gets two answers, and they are both useful, you can Upvote both of them, and then just Accept the one that you think is the best.  I'll keep trying to answer your questions even if you don't upvote, but I just though I would mention it :)